# Make condition in case I still have non-zero values

Tags: r

I would like to make a condition for the code below. I have the following code:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- structure(
  list(date1= c("2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28",
                "2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28"),
       date2 = c("2021-06-30","2021-06-30","2021-07-02","2021-07-07","2021-07-07","2021-07-09","2021-07-09","2021-07-09"),
       Code = c("FDE","ABC","ABC","ABC","CDE","FGE","ABC","CDE"),
       Week= c("Wednesday","Wednesday","Friday","Wednesday","Wednesday","Friday","Friday","Friday"),
       DR1 = c(4,1,4,3,3,4,3,5),
       DR01 = c(4,1,4,3,3,4,3,6), DR02= c(4,2,6,7,3,2,7,4),DR03= c(9,5,4,3,3,2,1,5),
       DR04 = c(5,4,3,3,6,2,1,9),DR05 = c(5,4,5,3,6,2,1,9),
       DR06 = c(2,4,3,3,5,6,7,8),DR07 = c(2,5,4,4,9,4,7,8),
       DR08 = c(0,0,0,1,2,0,0,0),DR09 = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),DR010 = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),DR011 = c(4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0), 
       DR012 = c(0,0,0,3,0,0,0,5),DR013 = c(0,0,1,0,0,0,2,0),DR014 = c(0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0)),
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))

dmda<-"2021-07-09"
CodeChosse<-"FGE"

df2<-df1 %>%
  filter(date2 == dmda, Code == CodeChosse)

      date1      date2 Code   Week DR1 DR01 DR02 DR03 DR04 DR05 DR06 DR07 DR08 DR09 DR010 DR011 DR012 DR013 DR014
1 2021-06-28 2021-07-09  FGE Friday   4    4    2    2    2    2    6    4    0    0     0     0     0     0     2

x<-colnames(df2 %>% select(starts_with("DR0")) %>% select(which(colSums(.) == 0)))

[1] "DR08"  "DR09"  "DR010" "DR011" "DR012" "DR013"
```

Notice that the code above selects the columns that are equal to zero in `df2`. However, see in `df2`, that I still have the value of the last column, which in this case is equal to 2. So in these cases, where I still have values that are different from 0, I would like `x` to be equal to `character (0)`. I believe you need to make an `if` condition for this. For example  `if(.......) return(character(0))`

Comment: Hi @JVieira, were you able to figure this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Get name of target columns
cols <- colnames(df2)[grep(pattern = "DR0", x = colnames(df2))]

# Return column names if column sum is 0
# If column sum is not zero, return NA
unname(ifelse(colSums(df2[,cols]) == 0, colnames(df2[,cols]), NA))
#>  [1] NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      "DR08"  "DR09" 
#> [10] "DR010" "DR011" "DR012" "DR013" NA
```

data:

```
df2 <- structure(list(date1 = "2021-06-28", date2 = "2021-07-09", Code = "FGE", 
                      Week = "Friday", DR1 = 4L, DR01 = 4L, DR02 = 2L, DR03 = 2L, 
                      DR04 = 2L, DR05 = 2L, DR06 = 6L, DR07 = 4L, DR08 = 0L, DR09 = 0L, 
                      DR010 = 0L, DR011 = 0L, DR012 = 0L, DR013 = 0L, DR014 = 2L), class = "data.frame", row.names = "1")
```

Created on 2022-03-31 by the reprex package (v2.0.1)